# Is this a bad use of eval()

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm a bit stuck trying to work out how to get around using eval(). Basically I need to use a string further down in my code however the presence of the quotation marks seem to muck it up and so my way around it has been to eval my original var...

```
$( "input" ).click(function( event ) {
    layerClicked = event.target.value;
    layerClicked = eval(layerClicked);

        if (map.hasLayer(layerClicked)) {
            map.removeLayer(layerClicked);
        }
        else{
            map.addLayer(layerClicked);
        } ;
});
```

Is this a legit and acceptable use of eval or have I missed something more basic?

Thanks in advance,
Rowan

Comment: I'm going to edit the value attribute of `event.target` in my browser.

Comment: "eval is evil", what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im working with the leaflet.js api and on click of a checkbox Im either removing or adding a layer from or to the map. So on click I'm getting the value of the checkbox and using that in my remove statement, problem is that it doesn't like quotation marks...

Comment: This smells a lot like an XY problem.

Comment: if it's just a string literal, you can use JSON.parse() instead of eval()

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are trying to access a global variable value when clicking an input. An alternative to that would be placing all these values you want to access into an object. This way you could use the bracket notation to access them, and eval would not be necessary.

```
var layers = {
    a: 'a value',
    b: 'b value',
    c: 'c value'
};

$("input").click(function(event) {
    var layerClicked = event.target.value;
    alert(layers[layerClicked]);
});
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/rqo6tcy4/

Comment: Hi Guilherme, That seems to be what I want to do, thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Yes you need to get some identifier property for your layers that corresponds to the values of the checkboxes. Then use this identifier to find the right layer to remove.

Answer (score 0):

The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument.

If the argument is an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If the argument is one or more JavaScript statements, eval() executes the statements.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but since that layerclicked seems to be not a mathematical expression nor a chunk javascript statement, you are doing it wrong...